# Different results of rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex in playground and in app

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode, swift-playground

rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex works differently in playground and in App, in playground mentioned below code returns as expected (location: 0, length: 4)

```
let flagRange = "".rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex(0)
```

But in application it returns (location: 0, length: 2)

Comment: What do you get in both if you change the `3` to `0` or `1`?

Comment: For 0 and 1: (location: 0, length: 4) - in playground, and (location: 0, length: 2) in app

Comment: In app, are you running on a device or the simulator? Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit device?

Comment: You are right, on simulator it works as expected  (location: 0, length: 4), but on device (in my case it is iPhone6 64-bit) it returns (location: 0, length: 2). Why does it work this way? Is there any other way to find proper range of unicode character

Comment: Had to use enumerateSubstringsInRange with .ByComposedCharacterSequences argument to workaround character range issue