# Counting characters in golang string

Tags: string, unicode, go, emoji, string-length

I am trying to count "characters" in go. That is, if a string contains one printable "glyph", or "composed character" (or what someone would ordinarily think of as a character), I want it to count 1. For example, the string "Hello, 世界", should count 11, since there are 11 characters, and a human would look at this and say there are 11 glyphs.

utf8.RuneCountInString() works well in most cases, including ascii, accents, asian characters and even emojis. However, as I understand it runes correspond to code points, not characters. When I try to use basic emojis it works, but when I use emojis that have different skin tones, I get the wrong count: https://play.golang.org/p/aFIGsB6MsO

From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569018/can-a-character-span-multiple-runes-in-go) and [here](https://blog.golang.org/normalization)  the following should work, but I still don't seem to be getting the right results (it over-counts):

```
func CountCharactersInString(str string) int {
    var ia norm.Iter
    ia.InitString(norm.NFC, str)
    nc := 0
    for !ia.Done() {
        nc = nc + 1
        ia.Next()
    }
    return nc
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
func GraphemeCountInString(str string) int {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("\\PM\\pM*|.")
    return len(re.FindAllString(str, -1))
}
```

I am looking for something similar to this in Objective C:

```
+ (NSInteger)countCharactersInString:(NSString *) string {
    // --- Calculate the number of characters enterd by user and update character count label
    NSInteger count = 0;
    NSUInteger index = 0;
    while (index < string.length) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:index];
        count++;
        index += range.length;
    }
    return count;
 }
```

Comment: You're looking for an implementation of the ["Grapheme Cluster Boundary" algorithm from UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).

Comment: I believe that's right. I tried both implementations for grapheme counting from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26728555/547291, but I run into the same trouble, but perhaps grapheme cluster boundary counting is more what I want?

Comment: The answers to that question confuse "grapheme clusters" with "character normalisation" (all have serious errors in them).

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? The problem is the skin-tone modifier is being counted as a separate character and norm does not "count" it as 1 character with the hand.

Comment: Never found a correct solution, so I had to loosen my requirements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote a package that allows you to do this: https://github.com/rivo/uniseg. It breaks strings according to the rules specified in [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) which is what you are looking for. Here is how you would use it in your case:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/rivo/uniseg"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(uniseg.GraphemeClusterCount("Hello, 世界"))
}
```

This will print `11` as you expect.

Comment: Best solution. All the other solutions result in counting some emojis as 1 character and other emojis as 2 characters.

Comment: There is a difference between bytes, runes, and graphemes, and it seems many people confuse the three. (In most use cases, it doesn't matter anyway.) For example, ️‍ (rainbow flag emoji) is 1 grapheme, 4 runes, and 14 bytes. The Go stdlib only has built-in functions for bytes and runes but not for graphemes.

Answer (score 17):

Straight forward natively use the `utf8.RuneCountInString()`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    str := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println("counts =", utf8.RuneCountInString(str))
}
```

Comment: or even more straight with utf8.RuneCountInString

Comment: Thanks for modification @mvndaai  RuneCountInString is like RuneCount but its input is a string instead of byte.

Comment: This is best answer cause it's used internal utf8 library instead of external

Comment: Go doesn't need a package to understand unicode. Just make sure you count runes and not bytes; `len([]rune("Hello, 世界"))`.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried [strings.Count](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Count)?

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
     "strings"
 )

 func main() {
     fmt.Println(strings.Count("Hello, 世界", "")) // Returns 2
 }
```

Comment: In the example "Hello, 世界", I would want it to count 11, since there are 11 characters, not 2. I will edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Reference to the example of API document.
https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#example_DecodeLastRuneInString

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    str := "Hello, 世界"
    count := 0
    for len(str) > 0 {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(str)
        count++
        fmt.Printf("%c %v\n", r, size)

        str = str[:len(str)-size]
    }
    fmt.Println("count:",count)
}
```

Comment: That counts *runes*, not *graphemes*: `str := ""` counts 2 instead of 1.

Comment: what "AX" is and why it should be 1?

Comment: It's `U+1F1E6 U+1F1FD`, which should render as the flag of the Åland Islands. Any other regional indicator symbol will have the same result (perhaps `` renders better on your system?).

Comment: but `U+1F1E6` and `U+1F1FD` can be two separate characters too, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but in a regional indicator sequence they form one grapheme (or "one printable 'glyph'" as the original question put it).

Comment: Apparently there is a 'unicode/norm' package to normalize unicode grapheme, is that what's needed here : https://blog.golang.org/normalization ?

Comment: how could we will think a colorful flag picture is a "glyph" or a "character"? And I find the is Objective C function rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex @Bjorn Roche used plays different in different system(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831455/different-results-of-rangeofcomposedcharactersequenceatindex-in-playground-and-i). I'm totally confused by the complex Emoji!

Comment: @phtrivier, yes, the examples I gave in my question use the unicode/norm package, but I still get the wrong answer sometimes, such as for the  glyph.

Comment: there is a standard function - utf8.RuneCountInString

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest way to do this would be like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := "Hello, 世界"
    var counter int
    for range str {
        counter++
    }
    fmt.Println(counter)
}
```

This one prints **11**